# SQL Server Rank Function without taking into account some flagged values

Tags: sql-server, rank

Here is my problem: I have a list of flagged values, I want to see where those values would be in the case they weren't flagged. But I don't want the other flagged values to influence the order.

Note: Flagged values are the ones with CurrentPlace 10000

```
ID  Value   CurrentPlace
------------------------    
1    2          1 
2    8          3 
3    3          2 
4    4      10000
5    5      10000
6   10      10000
```

Using:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         id, value,  
         rank() over (order by Value asc) as Rank
     from
         tbl1) r
where 
    r.ID in (select id from tbl1 where CurrentPlace = 10000)
```

Desired output:

```
ID  Value   Rank 
------------------
4     4       3 
5     5       3
6    10       4
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
ID  Value   Rank 
------------------
4      4    3 
5      5    4 
6     10    6
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you guys

### I've solved with

```
SELECT ID, Value, Rank 
FROM tbl1 a 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT isnull(max(currentPlace),0) + 1 AS Rank FROM tbl1 WHERE value < a.value and currentPlace <> 10000) b
WHERE a.CurrentPlace = 10000
```

Please feel free to comment this out.

Comment: What is the logic on ID 4 and 5 of the same Rank?

Comment: For some consistency process I need to check the posible rank of those records, checking later if those values are in top ten position, but if the flagged values arent discarted for more records it might be (in another example) rank: 9, 10, 11, and rank 11 would be out, when Rank 9, 9, 9 for instance would be inside top ten.